# How to concatenate multiple byte arrays into single string in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

For example, here are some byte arrays:

```
byte[] firstArray = "first part ".getBytes();
byte[] secondArray = "second part ".getBytes();
byte[] thirdArray = "third part ".getBytes();
```

Now, I want to concatenate them into single string, just like this:

```
(String) "first part second part third part ";
```

One possible solution here is to concatenate arrays into a new array and convert the new array to a string.But, I think it causes a unnecessary copy.
I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: `String` is logically a `char[]`, not `byte[]`. Don't confuse the two. You can extract the bytes from a string, using a particular character encoding, but you need to make sure that all chars can be represented within that character encoding, otherwise you will lose information.

Comment: Why do you need to concatenate the bytes? Why not just concatenate the strings?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only use arrays, you can figure out the total size and copy the parts into that array.

```
    byte[] firstArray = "first part ".getBytes();
    byte[] secondArray = "second part ".getBytes();
    byte[] thirdArray = "third part ".getBytes();

    byte[] finalArray = new byte[firstArray.length + secondArray.length + thirdArray.length];
    System.arraycopy(firstArray, 0, finalArray, 0, firstArray.length);
    System.arraycopy(secondArray, 0, finalArray, firstArray.length, secondArray.length);
    System.arraycopy(thirdArray, 0, finalArray, firstArray.length + secondArray.length, thirdArray.length);
    return new String(finalArray);
```